# Django/Python: Import package with configs project-wide

Tags: python

In my project I'm using a certain package `mb`, which I can configure like so:

```
mb.set_useragent("**", "1.0", "**@gmail.com")
mb.set_hostname("http://sss")
```

Right now I'm importing the package with `import mb` and then doing the configuration in each file where I use this package, but I want to be able to set the above for the package **once** and for these configs to be set every-time I import the package.

How can this be achieved in an effective manner? I don't want to wrap it in a function and return an object because then I'll have to do `wrapp_function_name().package_capability("param")` and it looks ugly.

Comment: Maybe, initialize it in `settings.py`?

Comment: Definitely thought of that just wasn't sure it was the "Python" way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a singleton class wrapper. In brief in singleton design pattern you will only have one instance from a class not more and every time you instantiate that class it will return that one instance. do it once for ever. like this.

```
class SingletonMb:
instance = None
def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    if not cls.instance:
        cls.instance = mb
        cls.instance.set_useragent("**", "1.0", "**@gmail.com")
        cls.instance.set_hostname("http://sss")
        return cls.instance
    else:  
        return cls.instance
```

and whenever you want to use the configured mb you can use `SingletonMb()` that refers to that one single configured object that is made from mb. and use package capability like this:

```
configuredMb = SingletonMb()

configuredMb.package_capability("param")
```

Comment: If my answer has helped you tick it as correct answer and upvote it.